error 404 on tomcat image on docker, even if inside webapps folder there is the app
I’m new to docker and I have almost the same issue reported in:
https://forums.docker.com/t/tomcat-give-error-404/95130
The main difference is that I do not have a webapp.dist directory created but in my case there is my app inside the webapp directory, and from looking at the log it has been deployed correctely.
If I run the application on my instance of tomcat  9.0 and JDK17 (without using docker) it works rights.
I follow an example found on internet at
https://www.cprime.com/resources/blog/deploying-your-first-web-app-to-tomcat-on-docker/
the changes are:

the version of java
the version of tomcat
the war that is going to be deployed: my app using spring-boot (but tomcat "inside"    spring-boot has been excluded);

This is my dockerfile
FROM tomcat:9.0-alpine
LABEL maintainer="francesco"

ADD assessmentonline.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [“catalina.sh”, “run”]

to build and execute the commad:
docker build -t mywebapp1 .
and
docker run -p 80:8080 mywebapp1
Looking at the log:
22-Oct-2024 14:24:34.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 494 ms
22-Oct-2024 14:24:34.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
22-Oct-2024 14:24:34.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.2
22-Oct-2024 14:24:34.566 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/assessmentonline.war]
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.019 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.143 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/assessmentonline.war] has finished in [3,575] ms
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.143 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples]
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [170] ms
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.326 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [12] ms
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.326 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs]
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.339 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [13] ms
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.339 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager]
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [19] ms
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.373 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [14] ms
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.376 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [“http-nio-8080”]
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.383 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [“ajp-nio-8009”]
22-Oct-2024 14:24:38.387 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 3865 ms

If I go to the filesystem using Docker:

but if I try to call it

C:\Windows\system32>curl http://localhost/assessmentonline/api/healthcheck
HTTP Status 404 – Not Foundh1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /assessmentonline/api/healthcheck

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.2

What can be the cause of this? how I can indagate further
